# Accessing EditText Android

Tags: android

I have a MainActivity with activity_main Layout.
in activity_main layout i have 4 Fragments.
in one of these fragments i have 2 text box and 1 button. its a login form.
when i click on this button i want to know what is that text inside textbox.
in MainActivity i defined Textbox with findviewbyid. but when i click on button i cant get text inside text view.

what should i do?

activity_main :

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.decoration.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
android:background="#FFFFFF" 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

   <TableRow android:layout_weight="1" 
       android:gravity="top">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/UpLeft"
        android:name="com.example.decoration.UpLeftFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="left"  />




    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/UpRight"
        android:name="com.example.decoration.UpRightFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"  />


   </TableRow>


   <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="bottom" >



    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/DownLeft"
        android:name="com.example.decoration.DownLeftFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
                    android:gravity="left" />



       <fragment
        android:id="@+id/DownRight"
        android:name="com.example.decoration.DownRightFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
                    android:gravity="right" />

   </TableRow>
```

down_left_fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:background="#761F01"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/bottomleft" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Usernme"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/txtedges"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:singleLine="true" />

   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="3dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Password"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/txtedges"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="3dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/SignInBtn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/btnedges"
    android:text="SignIn"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/Save"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="right|end"
    android:text="Save"
    android:textColor="#F7BA00" />
```

DownLeftFragment.java :

```
public class DownLeftFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.down_left_fragment,  container, false);
}
}
```

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final EditText a = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.Username);
    Button Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInBtn);
    Login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
            {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
            String n = a.getText().toString();
            login(n);
            }
    });


public void login(String a)
{...
}
```

Comment: What happens? Is there Any error in your logcat?

Comment: If your views are in your fragment, you have to call findViewById() on the fragment's view.

Comment: cn you post your full code

Comment: @ElDuderino Fragment's view can accessible in its own activity.

Comment: I edited the code above, can u help me now? i cant access to editText's text

Answer (score 1):

Don't get a new reference of the `EditText` inside your `onClick()`, because it will be a different object as the one where the user has done the input.

In addition, as ElDuderino suggested, if you have a layout for a Fragment get the instance of the Views with `findViewById(..)` in your Fragment. This way if the View isn't needed anymore it can be gargabe collected along with the Fragment. Otherwise it will be alive as long the Activity is.

Edit:

Try this in your Fragment:

```
public class DownLeftFragment extends Fragment {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.down_left_fragment,  container, false);
        EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.Username);
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignInBtn);
        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
                String n = edit.getText().toString();
                login(n);
             }
        });

        return root;
    }
    public void login(String a) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Your MainActivity looks like this now:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

This way all VIews belong to the Fragment which inflates the specific layout.

Comment: I did as u said, but it still not work, i edited my post, i write all of codes.

Comment: @PsylentStriker See my edit. This is the way to go. Maybe you have to modify your needs a bit but it should work.